# How to Hide a UIProgressView in Swift IOS

Tags: swift

I have a progress view that is initialized in the following code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var progressView: UIProgressView!
```

I am trying to figure out how to hide this progress view. I looked through Apples documentation at: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIProgressView_Class/ 
but it does not directly state any function to hide the UIProgressView. Is it possible to hide an UIProgressView and if so, how can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

In Swift 3 use:

```
progressView.isHidden = true
```

Answer (score 1):

UIProgressView inherits from UIView, so this should do the trick:

```
progressView.hidden = true
```

See here for more details: https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/hidden